# Subselects in JPA

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, subquery

I'm trying to run an application with jpa but I have the next mistake:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-8025] (Eclipse    Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [Oferta.findByLocalizacion: SELECT o FROM Oferta o WHERE o.negocioCif IN (SELECT cif FROM Negocio WHERE Direccion LIKE :direccion)], line 1, column 70: unexpected token [WHERE].
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(79@[1327:1: subselectIdentificationVariableDeclaration[List varDecls] : ( identificationVariableDeclaration[varDecls] | n= associationPathExpression ( AS )? i= IDENT ( join )* | n= collectionMemberDeclaration );])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:275)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper._getDelegate(EntityManagerWrapper.java:208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.getCriteriaBuilder(EntityManagerWrapper.java:895)
    at com.agrupadosobligatorio.persistencia.AbstractFacade.findRange(AbstractFacade.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5366)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5338)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5326)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
    ... 56 more
```

The file where is the query is this one:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "oferta")
 @XmlRootElement
 @NamedQueries({
   ................
 @NamedQuery(name = "Oferta.findByLocalizacion", query = "SELECT o FROM Oferta o WHERE o.negocioCif IN (SELECT cif FROM Negocio WHERE Direccion LIKE :direccion)"),
  .........................})

public class Oferta implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Basic(optional = false)
 @Column(name = "idoferta")
 private Integer idoferta;
 @Basic(optional = false)
 @NotNull
 @Column(name = "fecha_inicio")
 @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
 private Date fechaInicio;
 @Basic(optional = false)
 @NotNull
 @Column(name = "fecha_fin")
 @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
 private Date fechaFin;
 @Basic(optional = false)
 @NotNull
 @Size(min = 1, max = 150)
 @Column(name = "descripcion")
 private String descripcion;
 // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
 @Basic(optional = false)
 @NotNull
 @Column(name = "precio_inicial")
 private BigDecimal precioInicial;
 @Basic(optional = false)
 @NotNull
 @Column(name = "precio_final")
 private BigDecimal precioFinal;
 @JoinColumn(name = "negocio_cif", referencedColumnName = "cif")
 @ManyToOne(optional = false)
 private Negocio negocioCif;
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "ofertaIdoferta")
 private Collection<Cupon> cuponCollection;

public Oferta() {
}

public Oferta(Integer idoferta) {
    this.idoferta = idoferta;
}

public Oferta(Integer idoferta, Date fechaInicio, Date fechaFin, String descripcion, BigDecimal precioInicial, BigDecimal precioFinal) {
    this.idoferta = idoferta;
    this.fechaInicio = fechaInicio;
    this.fechaFin = fechaFin;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.precioInicial = precioInicial;
    this.precioFinal = precioFinal;
}

public Integer getIdoferta() {
    return idoferta;
}

public void setIdoferta(Integer idoferta) {
    this.idoferta = idoferta;
}

public Date getFechaInicio() {
    return fechaInicio;
}

public void setFechaInicio(Date fechaInicio) {
    this.fechaInicio = fechaInicio;
}

public Date getFechaFin() {
    return fechaFin;
}

public void setFechaFin(Date fechaFin) {
    this.fechaFin = fechaFin;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public BigDecimal getPrecioInicial() {
    return precioInicial;
}

public void setPrecioInicial(BigDecimal precioInicial) {
    this.precioInicial = precioInicial;
}

public BigDecimal getPrecioFinal() {
    return precioFinal;
}

public void setPrecioFinal(BigDecimal precioFinal) {
    this.precioFinal = precioFinal;
}

public Negocio getNegocioCif() {
    return negocioCif;
}

public void setNegocioCif(Negocio negocioCif) {
    this.negocioCif = negocioCif;
}

@XmlTransient
public Collection<Cupon> getCuponCollection() {
    return cuponCollection;
}

public void setCuponCollection(Collection<Cupon> cuponCollection) {
    this.cuponCollection = cuponCollection;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (idoferta != null ? idoferta.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Oferta)) {
        return false;
    }
    Oferta other = (Oferta) object;
    if ((this.idoferta == null && other.idoferta != null) || (this.idoferta != null && !this.idoferta.equals(other.idoferta))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.agrupadosobligatorio.bean.Oferta[ idoferta=" + idoferta + " ]";
}
```

}

So you can see the mistake is on the subselect and I don't know how to solve it. Please, could you help me with this?.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You are missing Negocio entity name in subselect, try with:

```
SELECT o FROM Oferta o WHERE o.negocioCif IN (SELECT cif FROM Negocio cif WHERE cif.Direccion LIKE :direccion)
```

Or you can try directly with:

```
SELECT o FROM Oferta o WHERE o.negocioCif.Direccion=:direccion
```